# How should i create a third table for new Categories in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm developing a practice project where I have 2 tables. An article table with heading and text and a user table. Now I want an admin (which I created in the database before) to create additional Article Categories. Does anyone have an idea how I can link my tables or my models now ? I've only been working with Laravel for a week now and don't quite look through it yet.

That are my tables :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('heading',80);
        $table->string('clubchoose')->default('DEFAULT');
        $table->text('text');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedInteger('author')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('author')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
    });
}
```

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->boolean('isAdmin')->default(false);
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: you can use migrations from laravel. so to create a new table, you create a new migration, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-tables

Comment: So you want for an article to have one category, and category can have many articles?

Comment: so I have created 3 fixed categories for sports clubs and users can select these 3 categories in the view and write a post about it. Now I want the only that admin can create new categories and I don't know how to change my database model or if I create a create_arictle table how to do that only an admin can create new categories :( edit: and yes an article should belong to one category about one specific club

Comment: So you need to create a "category" model and then create a foreign key "category_id" in your article model which holds the id of the category. To create a new category you just have to enter a new entry in the "category" table. In the article creation form you need to loop through all categories of the category table so that the users can choose one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to achieve that, you first need to create your categories model/controller/table:

```
php artisan make:model Category -m //-m flag creates migration automatically

php artisan make:controller CategoryController --reosource //--resource flag creates a CRUD controller.
```

After that, inside your categories table, add column article_id (and other fields you want):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // ...
            $table->integer('article_id')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

After that, you need to alter your articles table by adding category_id column. To do that, create a new migration to add that just one column:

```
php artisan make:migration add_category_id_to_articles_table --table==articles
```

Inside that migration, add this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('category_id')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Now that you have migrations set up, you need to set up relations. Inside your Article model, add this relation:

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

So an article will belong to category. For the categories, as they will have more than one article, add this relation:

```
public function articles(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

So now, you have everything set up. Run migrations, and add some categories and test things out. Let me know if you have any errors or troubles.

EDIT:

If you want only an admin to add new categories, you could create a button that is only visible for admins. Something like this:

```
@if(Auth->user()->role == 'admin'){
   //show button
@endif
```

Comment: you shouldn't need the `article_id` on the `categories` table

Comment: Yeah you're right, but this could make things easier if you want to see all the articles that belong to specific category. I tend to like this approach

Comment: thank you for the detailed help. I understood it and hope that I can implement it :) !

Comment: but a category doesn't belong to an article (which is what having an `article_id` key on `categories` implies), no relationship you are setting up uses that key

Comment: @lagbox Oh got it now, I inverted the logic. Don't mind me, It's still early in the morning, haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: @LearningHoon no problem. Good luck. If this answer helps you solving your problem, consider marking it as an answer.

Comment: I still have a Question about the Controller. I want to create a public function store( Category $categorie) and I safe the request with $categorie->categories_name ( the col for the categories name in my database) and just $categorie->save(). but I doesnt work x (

Comment: Instead of `Category $categorie` in your function, use `Request $request`. In order to use data from your form that you submitted, you need a [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests) Request class